# How to add multiple message validation in only one growl message

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, growl

I have a p:growl for show message validation, but it shows a growl for each message validation, is there any way to show multiples messages validation in only one message p:growl?

Answer (score 0):

It's just how the `growl` works. Each message will appear in its own panel. I don't think you can change it unless you develop a custom `growl` component on your own and put `<p:messages>` in it :)

Answer (score 0):

As Mr.J4mes has mentioned, it's not a 'add on' function of Growl, you could however get PrimeFaces source and recompile it with your changes/requirements.

GrowlRenderer, puts all of the messages into a JSON object e.g..
{summary:"Successful",detail:"Hello ss",severity:'info'},{summary:"Second Message",detail:"Additional Info Here...",severity:'info'}]});});

Then the grow.js line 32 does a for each loop of 'each mesage', and does a render... using renderMessage on line 50. (may may not change depends fversion you're using)...

basically, you could do several things to fix it, (ie pass in all objects not for each and do it in the renderMessage, or keep as is but just don't end the tags until all messages are finished)..

This is less work than creating your own widget etc, adding a var to the primefaces widget, and conditionally doing this is probably a better option - otherwise you're totlally overwriting the functionality.